# If...Else: If iFrame exists, apply CSS to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, header

I'm new here. And very new to programming, markup, web dev. I do have some basic understanding of HTML and CSS, but this is my first attempt at using jQuery/Javascript.

Is it possible to use jQuery (or otherwise) to

1- detect if an iframe with **class="iframe1"** appears on a given page and

2- if it does exist, to remove the primary navigation bar with **id="main-header"** ?

I'm currently using this custom CSS to hide the navigation globally:

```
#main-header {
display:none !important;
}
```

and then using this (for example) to replace it on individual pages:

```
.page-id-1350 #main-header {
display:block !important;
}
```

Obviously this is not ideal, and I very much like to automate this process.

Thanks very much in advance,

Chris

Comment: Do you need this done in plain JavaScript or is jQuery alright? Also, perhaps a better option would be pure CSS. But for that, I must ask: does the `#main-header` have to be visible on all pages with the `.page-id-###` class? Any other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery code to do just that:

```
if($(".iframe1").length > 0) // If .iframe1 exists
    $("#main-header").hide(); // Hide #main-header
```

Or, go the opposite way, keep your CSS that hides `#main-header` and then show it when `.frame1` is not present on the page:

```
if($(".iframe1").length == 0) // If .iframe1 does not exists
    $("#main-header").show(); // Show #main-header
```

Comment: So after fiddling with my options, I ended up needing to REMOVE the navigation from select pages. It was just cleaner that way. So I used an iteration of your first code chunk like this: 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script‌​> <script> $( document ).ready(function() { if($(".iframe1").length > 0) // If .iframe1 exists $("#main-header").hide(); // Hide #main-header }); </script>`
 Thanks very much. I would upvote you if I had enough cred. :P

Comment: If you feel like this post is the answer to your question, you can click on "Accept", so other people who search similar issues and find your post know that this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the help @mbinette! I'm glad to have made my first foray into jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with JavaScript, with code like this:

```
<script>
// Place this at the end of the body
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var iframeTest = document.querySelectorAll("iframe.iframe1");
    var navBar = document.getElementById("main-header");
    if (iframeTest.length > 0) {
        navBar.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    }
});
</script>
```